# Prove that the columns of the first matrix span but the columns of the second matrix do not span.

Tags: linear-algebra

A = [1 0 1 0]  = row 1 
    [1 2 0 1]  = row 2
(2 * 4 matrix)

and [0 0] = row 1
    [2 1] = row 2

(2 * 2 matrix)

I know that Column of matrix of m*n dimension spans if rank of matrix is equal to m.
If columns of A span then m<= n but if columns are linearly independent m>=n. And matrix is invertible if columns span and are linearly independent. So if a matrix is invertible matrix is a square matrix.

Comment: I'm confused by your opening statements. What is A? How are you identifying rows?

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) \quad \text{and} \quad 
B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0  \\
2 & 1  
\end{array}\right)$$

are the two matrices you're talking about, and assuming the space which the columns may or may not span is $\mathbf{R}^2$, then one can see that the columns of $A$ span $\mathbf{R}^2$ since among the set of vectors making up the columns we have the two standard basis vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ (that is, columns $3$ and $4$), of $\mathbf{R}^2$. Whereas, to see that the columns of $B$ don't span $\mathbf{R}^2$ notice that the first column is a scalar multiple of the second, namely, $(0,2) = 2\cdot (0,1)$, thus the two vectors making up the columns of $B$ span the $y$-axis, not all of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Comment: can you do a rigorous proof that's what I don't know how to do

Comment: The columns of the first span because given any vector $(a,b) \in \mathbf{R}^2$ we have that $a(1,0) + b(0,1) = (a,b)$. Whereas, the columns of the second don't because (for example) any vector of the form $(a, 0)$ is not in the span, that is, for no scalars $c$ and $d$ do we have that $c(0,2) + d(0,1) = (a,0)$

Comment: why do you want a vector of form (a,0) for the second matrix. why not of form (a,b)

Comment: Well technically the vector $(a,0)$ is of the form $(a,b)$ just with $b = 0$. The reason for the difference is because in the first case you want to show that the columns span, thus you need to show that for any vector in $\mathbf{R}^2$ some linear combination of the columns will yield that vector. In the second case you want to show that the columns _do not_ span, and one way to do this is to produce a vector in $\mathbf{R}^2$ that does not lie in the span (i.e. no linear combination of the columns equals that vector). My point was that anything that looks like $(a,0)$ is not in their span.

Comment: Is (0,b) in the span for matrix two

Comment: Yes, $(0,b)$ is definitely in the span.

Comment: if matrix two were [0 2; 2 0] would the columns span R^2?

Comment: Yes, assuming the rows of the matrix are $[0\ 2]$ and $[2\ 0]$, then the columns would span $\mathbf{R}^2$, because given any vector $\left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right) \in \mathbf{R}^2$ we could write it as a linear combination of the columns, namely, $\frac{a}{2}\left(\begin{matrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) + \frac{b}{2}\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: I wrote the vectors vertically just for clarity.